# How to underline text off-center?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I want the text underline to be off centered and overlapping text. I am not sure how to accomplish this. What is the best way to replicate the following effect?

[image]

**Current Code:**

```css
.title {
  font-style: italic;
}

.titleWrapper {
  border-bottom: 20px solid var(--main-accent-color);
}
```

```html
<div className="titleWrapper">
  <h2 className="title">About Me</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text-indent` with negative values can help you here:

```css
.title {
  --i: 20px;

  width: fit-content;
  box-shadow: 0 -10px red inset;
  text-indent: calc(-1*var(--i));
  padding-right: var(--i);
  margin-left: var(--i);
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title">About Me</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to do this but perhaps easy is to create an accent element and position it from the container.
In a modern CSS `display:grid;` for the container would be perhaps a less "noisy" css but will leave that for another question.

Grid: overlap the grid columns (some extra borders to show where things are)  Content "style" is separated from the grid;

```css
:root {
  --main-accent-color: #ffdddd;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2rem 10rem 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  border: 1px dotted orange;
}

.grid-container>* {
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.title {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.title-accent {
  background-color: var(--main-accent-color);
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  height: 1rem;
}

.one {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.two {
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="titleWrapper grid-container">
  <h2 class="title one">About Me</h2>
  <div class="title-accent two">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Positioned:

```css
:root {
  --main-accent-color: #ffdddd;
}

.title {
  font-style: italic;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.titleWrapper .title-accent {
  display: absolute;
  margin-top: -0.25rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  border-top: 20px solid;
  border-top-color: var(--main-accent-color);
  width: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="titleWrapper">
  <h2 class="title">About Me</h2>
  <div class="title-accent"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not a best practice but works:

```css
.title .a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.title .rest {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: red;
  text-decoration-thickness: 3px;
}
```

```html
<h2 className='title'>
<span className='a'>A</span><span className="rest">bout Me</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: Your example doesn't work, unfortunately, because you left `className` in the HTML (it needs to be `class` to demonstrate your code running, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/94wsf36h/)), and because the right edge of the underline doesn't extend beyond the last character of the text.